# Application lost access of Oracle after character set change

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I changed the character set from we8mswin1252 to al32utf8 in Oracle using these commands.

```
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE

STARTUP RESTRICT

ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE AL32UTF8;

ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8;

SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE

STARTUP
```

Although my character set is changed, I lost the access from my application to all the current databases. I had to create another database to run the application. Is there a solution?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot connect anymore? shutdown then startup will surely disconnect current sessions.

Comment: Does your application handle connection lost and is it able to reconnect? Maybe an application restart would help instead of creating a new database.

Comment: I even restarted my system. But could connect with existing Databases I have created. I had to create a new DB.

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8` is de-supported since Oracle 10.1. Most likely you destroyed your database - hopefully you have a backup to restore it. For proper migration to UTF-8 follow the [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011)

Comment: In addition to `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET` being deprecated, you used the `INTERNAL_USE` clause that bypasses the (limited) sanity checks that the database would do before making this change.  That clause should **never** be used unless someone from Oracle Support specifically tells you to do so (and they almost certainly won't tell you to do so) because it will break the database if things aren't set up perfectly.  Definitely time to restore the backup and reconsider the migration approach.